# How to run package(marmap) without an error?

Tags: r

I previously started a question on how to avoide pie charts from overlapping, although I got NO answers! I finally could find a package that apparently can draw pie charts without overlapping.

```
install.packages(marmap)
library(marmap)
space.pies(x, y, pie.slices, pie.colors=NULL, pie.radius=1, pie.space=5, 
          link=TRUE, seg.lwd=1, seg.col=1, seg.lty=1, coord=NULL)
```

however, when I load the package, I receive this error

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘marmap’ in
> loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): 
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.2 is required
```

therefore, I cannnot run the "space.pies" function

How should I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states that the package you have loaded installed is outdated. Try updating the package, either using the GUI or

```
install.packages("rlang")
```

If you get another similar error message, update that package too.

Comment: I installed that package and loaded it, still receive the same error when using the space.pies function [Error in space.pies("Long", "Lat", data1, pie.colors = NULL, pie.radius = 1,  : 
  could not find function "space.pies"]

Comment: Well, it's not quite the same error. Did you reload `marmap` after updating `rlang`?

Comment: yes, I again updated the whole package, and loaded "marmap" and "rlang" both. the error is the same when I try to run that function, the  error presented in the main question is for when I load the main package(marmap), I still get that error though! but I load the "rlang" package separately after loading the main one, still no progress

Comment: I must say it would be way easier to debug if you posted a MWE... What happens when you type `library(marmap)`, then `example(space.pies)` ?

Comment: @Benoit the error is the same, function doesn't exist! cause package 'marmap' load failed, because the 'rlang' is outdated!! Warning message:
In example(space.pies) : no help found for ‘space.pies’

Comment: OK so shutdown R, re-open and then type `install.packages("rlang")`. Is the installation of `rlang` successful?

Comment: the installation is successful again, but the space.pies function is still not recognized

Comment: What installation is successful? `rlang` or `marmap` or both? What happens when you type `library(marmap)`? What happens when you type `example(space.pies)`? Please, be specific or we can't help you. Don't hesitate to post screenshots of both your commands and errors messages. That would help. Again, help us to help you.